# HTML5 Doctype for Domparser

Tags: html, xml, dtd, domparser

**Task:** I want to parse an XML document using DOMParser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). I have no and need no formal DTD and parsing this as "text/xml" worked pretty well. Now I want to use certain symbolic entities, such as **&nbsp;** in my xml and the parser, of course,  complains that they are not known. Since I want to be able to access, in principle, all existing html entities, I tried to use a doctype specification

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

and this worked as expected, since DOMParser seems to have this doctype and the connected entity list preloaded. However, this doctype is outdated. So I tried the new <!DOCYTPE html> but this did **not** work. Also this is expected, as the novel html5 doctype tag works differently than the older xml/sgml based ones.

**Question:** Is there some standardized !DOCTYPE for html (5) which the browser recognizes and which contains the preloaded HTML entities. (I do not want to copy in a list of all entities as separate entity definitions, the browser has them somewhere, I just do not know how to activate them by an xml/sgml style DTD for html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using XML, but don't want to use the XHTML doctype, then you *have* to declare the character entities of XHTML via `ENTITY` declarations directly in your document (in the internal subset or an external declaration set) since only HTML has `nbsp` and many others as predefined entities (XML has only `quot`, `amp`, `apos`, `lt`, and `gt`). You can use the HTML5 entity set from https://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/htmlmathml-f.ent (which includes the large set of MathML entities), or the much smaller set of classic HTML4 entities.

But I would first check if DomParser actually processes markup declarations and/or external declaration sets with markup declarations. Try to parse the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#xA0;">
]>
<test>
  &nbsp;
</test>
```

and check the console for error messages.

There is no "official" DTD for HTML (in fact, no formal grammar at all), but there's my [SGML DTD for W3C HTML 5.1](http://sgmljs.net/blog/blog1701.html) with much more information about parsing HTML5 than you probably are interested in, including info about HTML5's predefined entities.